# Connection between .xaml and .xaml.cs files are being lost every time I move or add new file

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I just installed VS2015 with Xamarin on windows and I followed the Quick guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/

At first the .xaml.cs file had a lot of errors in InitializeComponent() and every other reference to the items on the .xaml file like the Buttons and Entry as if they could not be found.

I thought it was a namespace problem and the two files were not aware of each other, and after trying many things I changed the "Class" attribute in the .xaml file, saved it and after realizing that it didn't solve the problem, I changed it back to the original name space x:Class="Phoneword.MainPage" and after saving, all the errors were gone.

Yay! I was happy, I thought it was just a first build problem, but now every time I move a file or create a new one, I have the same problem. Even when I create just a resource file inside a different directory. Every time, the only fix is to do the same procedure I just described.

It also happens when cleaning the project.

Really annoying and I don't know what's going to happen when I have more xaml files.

Any idea how to fix or why it is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Freakin outrageous that this is still a bug in VS for Mac 2019, nothing work from the below!!!

Comment: I gave up on Xamarin a long time ago... Go Flutter man, much better. Have bugs too, but the responses to them are much much faster and the devs are much more dedicated. Plus, Xamarin is now just a bunch of "workarounds" together and that's not good. Xamarin apps performance is degrading as they 'fix things'. The idea is great, but they should take a step back and do it all over from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

> Any idea how to fix or why it is happening?

As a workaround, at the moment, you can manually edit the `.csproj` to keep the connection between XAML and designer file.

For example:

```
<Compile Include="Pages\QuestionPage.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>QuestionPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

I would recommend filling a bug at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug

Comment: Thanks. Is it a known bug?

Comment: Also, where is this file?

Comment: Me i dont have .csproj file in VS17 on Mac

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that I quite like, which you can customise depending on your needs/desires.

For me, I wanted not only the `Foo.xaml.cs` file to be under `Foo.xaml`, but also a related `FooViewModel.cs`.

There is a gist here: https://gist.github.com/maxcalvin/9590e87eec0fd576f94539357930f859

But the gist of it similar to the previous answer by Prashant:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="**\*ViewModel.cs">
    <DependentUpon>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace(%(Identity), "ViewModel.cs", ".xaml"))</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Update="**\*.xaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace(%(Identity), ".cs", ""))</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the bin and obj folders. Unload the project and reload it. Clean and rebuild the solution. We found this issue when moving from vs2015 to vs2017

Answer (score 0):

I just unload and reload the PCL(Portable Class Libray) in the solution.It solved the problem.

Comment: I did this by using the visual studio  (IDE)
Go the solution right click on solution/ project there will be an option for load or unload the project/ clear solution etc

Comment: Ok Thanks for you reply. But this didnot work for me. I had to delete the Resources.Designer.cs and it was regenerated. This solved my problem. thanks